# Hiding typeclass instance declarations while importing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monoids, semigroup

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game, and I decided to construct types for cells (elements of the board) and the board as follows:

```
data Cell  = X | O deriving (Show, Eq)
type Board = [[Maybe Cell]]
```

Here, Nothing represents an empty cell, (Just X) and (Just O) represent cells filled with X and O respectively.

I would like to define (Maybe Cell) as a monoid as follows:

```
instance Monoid (Maybe Cell) where
  mempty             = Nothing
  mappend Nothing x  = x
  mappend (Just x) _ = (Just x)
```

And Board as another monoid with

```
instance Monoid Board where
  mempty = [[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
           ,[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
           ,[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]]
  mappend = zipWith (zipWith mappend) 
  -- where the right-hand-side mappend is the addition on (Maybe Cell)
```

I know I could implement this absolutely without monoids, but I'm trying to explore the field, and it's just a really neat way to write it.

The problem that I get is that a `Maybe` monoid instance is already defined in `GHC.Base` as follows:

```
instance Semigroup a => Monoid (Maybe a)
```

This has a very different definition than what I want, but it causes duplicate instance declarations, so I can't just ignore it.

What I'm trying to do is to hide the `Monoid` instance of `(Maybe a)` from `GHC.Base` to avoid duplicate instances. I tried searching a lot for that, but couldn't really find a way to hide that. I can't hide all of `Monoid` or all of `Semigroup`, because I need their functions, but I need to hide this specific instance declaration. Could anyone help me with that?

NOTE: I'm using FlexibleInstances.

Comment: You can't hide `instance` declarations. What you can do though is use a `newtype` to "wrap" the underlying types. This is done quite a lot even in the standard libraries - for example the `Sum` and `Product` types are both wrappers for `Int` (actually any instance of `Num`), with different `Monoid` instances.

Comment: oh, and your `Monoid` instance for `Maybe Cell` already exists as a `newtype` wrapper: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First

Comment: @RobinZigmond Wow! That was fast! It is correct; `First` solved the problem altogether. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I standard Haskell, class instances are always “completely global”<sup>†</sup> – if a type has an instance for a given class *somewhere*, then this instance is used everywhere.

So, if you want to define a separate instance, you need to either have a different class – usually not practical, including in your example – or a different type, which is usually not a problem. In fact Haskell has a dedicated keyword for this kind of thing, `newtype`. You simply change `type Board = [[Maybe Cell]]` to

```
newtype Board = Board [[Maybe Cell]]
```

and then

```
instance Semigroup Board where
  Board l <> Board r = Board $ zipWith (zipWith mappend) l r
instance Monoid Board where
  mempty = Board [[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
                 ,[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
                 ,[Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]]
  mappend = (<>)
```

Likewise, instead of `Maybe Cell` you should use another type that has the suitable `Monoid` instance. That one actually [exists already in the base library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:First), but it's not really necessary: you can just make a semigroup (not monoid!) instance for `Cell` itself which represents the left-bias, then `Maybe` will (since GHC-8.4) automatically have the desired behaviour.

```
instance Semigroup Cell where
  a <> _ = a
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>It has actually been proposed to relax this, allowing locally-selected instances, in [a paper presented at the 2018 Haskell Symposium](https://doi.org/10.1145/3242744.3242752).</sub>

Comment: TIL `First` is deprecated

Comment: @luqui ah good point, [`Semigroup.First`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:First) should be used instead of [`Monoid.First`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First).